# records with perfect correlation to the answer. Drop or Keep?

Tags: feature-selection, xgboost, correlation

I have about 1000 records (5 numeric, 5 categorical vars) and about 25 of them have something in 5-level categorical variable that just gives away answer. It's just too obvious and I'm not worried about over-fitting. I'm using methods are xgboost or catboost and wondering if keeping these hurt or improve fitting of other variables. When I just keep it, once in a while it gets 1 out of 25 in test set wrong and I just override that. I'm wondering if it's better to just leave those out and label 1 manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you mean that there are 25 instances out of 1000 for which some of the features correlate perfectly with the answer? If yes I don't see any reason to drop them, the model has to account for the 975 other instances as well.

Comment: @Erwan 1000 is number of training data, 10 is number of variables I have. One of those variables gives out answer for about 25 of my training data. (ie: trying to predict whether someone is dead, and say...variable named "status" column has healthy/sick/dead. It's weird situation where it doesn't any value to classify them using machine learning but I'm just trying to increase my accuracy at total level.

Comment: Ok I see. but then what happens to this particular variable for the 975 other instances? If it's missing or unhelpful to predict the answer for most instances, I don't think it's a problem in general but I'm not familiar with the methods you use.